# What does GAC uses to keep record of DLLs

Tags: c#, asp.net, gac

I have a Utility class dll added to GAC of front end live server.

Now I need to make copy of dll with another name and change a little bit of code in it.

If I copy renamed dll to GAC is it enough ? what if both dlls generated from different projects but both projects has same GUID or Public Key.

In short I don't want GAC to mix up my renamed dll to original dll

Comment: "*but when I go to Assembly Information it's blank*" - the Assembly.cs file isn't updated automatically, you need to do that manually.

Comment: Is it necessary to populate it ? or just renaming project will do the job

Comment: I think the GAC might use the information set in there for versioning, however, with regards to the name it will be registered as whatever name the DLL has.

Comment: To be honest, I am still not entirely sure what your issue was?

Comment: I updated my question, if it makes sense now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GAC uses an assemblies [strong-name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wd40t7ad%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to identify it, this is a combination of

> simple text name, version number, and culture information (if provided) — plus a public key and a digital signature

Given you are *renaming* the DLL then the GAC should identify your updated DLL as a completely different assembly so there should be no issues with overwriting the the original.